# Regular expression for email masking

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to write a regular expression to mask an email address. Example below.

> input: john.doe@example.en.com
>
> output: j*******@e*********.com

I have tried the following but I just can't seem to get it working correctly.

> regex:`(?<=.).(?=[^@]\*?@)`
>
> output:j*******@example.en.com
>
> regex:`(?<=.).(?=[^@]\*?)(?=[^\.]\*?\.)`
>
> output:j******************.com

Any help would be appreciated.
[demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZUGJDC/1)

Comment: Try [`.replaceAll("(?<=.).(?=[^@]*?@)|(?:(?<=@.)|(?!^)\\G(?=[^@]*$))(.)(?=.*\\.)", "*")`](https://regex101.com/r/Bwsy9X/1) (beware of garbage chars in this comment, do not copy/paste from here)

Comment: How important is the use of regular expressions to you? IMHO `.indexOf("@")` and some "substring-copy-paste" might be more readable in a couple of months.

Comment: @DerMike It's not important. I just got it stuck in my head that I needed to use a regex.

Comment: @Wiktor That regex works. If you submit it as an answer I will accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

## Update with various masking email solutions

- **`foo@bar.com` ⇒ `f**@b**.com`** (current question) - `s.replaceAll("(?<=.)[^@](?=[^@]*?@)|(?:(?<=@.)|(?!^)\\G(?=[^@]*$)).(?=.*\\.)", "*")` (see [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Bwsy9X/17))
- **`foo@bar.com` ⇒ `f**@b*r.com`** - `s.replaceAll("(?<=.)[^@](?=[^@]*?@)|(?:(?<=@.)|(?!^)\\G(?=[^@]*$)).(?=.*[^@]\\.)", "*")` (see [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Bwsy9X/19))
- **`foo@bar.com` ⇒ `f*o@b*r.com`** - `s.replaceAll("(?<=.)[^@](?=[^@]*?[^@]@)|(?:(?<=@.)|(?!^)\\G(?=[^@]*$)).(?=.*[^@]\\.)", "*")` (see [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Bwsy9X/20))
- **`foo@bar.com` ⇒ `f**@b*****m`** - `s.replaceAll("(?<=.)[^@](?=[^@]*?@)|(?:(?<=@.)|(?!^)\\G(?=[^@]*$)).(?!$)", "*")` (see [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Bwsy9X/18))
- **`foo@bar.com` ⇒ `f*o@b*****m`** - `s.replaceAll("(?<=.)[^@](?=[^@]*[^@]@)|(?:(?<=@.)|(?!^)\\G(?=[^@]*$)).(?!$)", "*")` (see [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qg72Rm/3))

## Original answer

In case you can't use a *code-based* solution, you may use

```
s.replaceAll("(?<=.)[^@](?=[^@]*?@)|(?:(?<=@.)|(?!^)\\G(?=[^@]*$)).(?=.*\\.)", "*")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Bwsy9X/17)

**What it does**:

- `(?<=.)[^@](?=[^@]*?@)` -any char other than `@` (`[^@]`) that is preceded by any single char (`(?<=.)`) and is followed with any 0 or more chars other than `@` up to a `@` (`(?=[^@]*?@)`)
- `|` - or
- `(?:(?<=@.)|(?!^)\\G(?=[^@]*$))`  - match a location in the string that is preceded with `@` and any char (`(?<=@.)`) or (`|`) the end of the previous successful match (`(?!^)\\G`) that is followed with any 0+ chars other than `@` uo to the end of string (`(?=[^@]*$)`)
- `.` - any single char
- `(?=.*\\.)` - followed with any 0+ chars up to the last `.` symbol in the string.

Comment: Wouldn't `\S+@\S+` do as well, for most email addresses?

Comment: @Robert: I do not believe you can use it for masking. You can use it for extracting most of emails.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, any example where we can do f@b.com to `*@*.**m`

Comment: @kakabali `s.replaceAll("[^@.](?!$)", "*")`

Comment: What can I do to get f\*o@b\*r.com.br ? I need the domain to be full visible

Comment: @user2494863 If you want to mask the domain part before the first dot, use `(?<=.)[^@\n](?=[^@\n]*?[^@\n]@)|(?:(?<=@.)|(?!^)\G(?=[^@\n]*$))[^.](?!\.)`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/Bwsy9X/106).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew besides the RegEx you proposed in the last comment, would it be possible to do the same replacement, but masking the e-mail in a larger string like a JSON for example? `{"name": "john.doe@example.en.com"} => {"name": "j***e@e***e.com"}`

Comment: @PavelRazgovorov Parse JSON first, it is not plain text. Use regex only on plain text.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Right now I'm extracting the email with a first RegEx and then replacing it with one of yours as a (repeated) second step. The string does not have to be a JSON, it could be any string: `"Send me an e-mail to john.doe@example.en.com" => "Send me an e-mail to j***e@e***e.en.com"`

Comment: does not work with short email addresses such as gp@m3.ru =(

Comment: @IvanSmorodin It depends what you need. [This works](https://regex101.com/r/Bwsy9X/151)., and [this works, too](https://regex101.com/r/Bwsy9X/152), also, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/Bwsy9X/153).

Answer (score 4):

How about this one if you do not need the masks having the same number of characters of the original strings (which is more anonymous):

```
(?<=^.)[^@]*|(?<=@.).*(?=\.[^.]+$)
```

For example, if you replace the matches with `***`, the result would be:

```
j***@e***.com
```