# Regular expression for masking emails

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to write a regular expression to mask an email address. Example below.

Input

```
john.doe@example.en.com
```

Output

```
j******e@e*********.com
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

I tried from below link but could not changed it.

[Regular expression for email masking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43003138/regular-expression-for-email-masking)

Comment: Regex cannot count so getting the correct number of asterisks is impossible without additional processing.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Can you please guide me to do the additional processing?

Comment: Could further think of replacing all [`(?<!@|^)[^@\s](?!@|\w*$)` with `*`](https://regex101.com/r/A6rSQu/1) but not sure if this is a good idea :) As a Java String: `"(?<!@|^)[^@\\s](?!@|\\w*$)"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Pattern and Matcher with this regex [`(.)(.*?)(.@.)(.*?)(\.[^\.]+)$`](https://regex101.com/r/rHO5DF/1/) which match many groups like so :

```
String email = "john.doe@example.en.com";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.)(.*?)(.@.)(.*?)(\\.[^\\.]+)$");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(email);
if (matcher.find()) {
    email = matcher.group(1) + matcher.group(2).replaceAll(".", "*") +
            matcher.group(3) + matcher.group(4).replaceAll(".", "*") +
            matcher.group(5);
}
```

**Output**

```
j******e@e*********.com
```

Comment: Nice on, albeit: this might be much easier to do "manually" by using string length and indexOf and so on.

Answer (score 2):

```
s.replaceAll("(?<=.)[^@\n](?=[^@\n]*?[^@\n]@)|(?:(?<=@.)|(?!^)\\G(?=[^@\n]*$)).(?=.*[^@\n]\\.)","*")
```

https://regex101.com/r/gpZZsL/2

Tried on `jshell`

```
jshell> var s = "john.doe@example.en.com"
s ==> "john.doe@example.en.com"

jshell> s.replaceAll("(?<=.)[^@\n](?=[^@\n]*?[^@\n]@)|(?:(?<=@.)|(?!^)\\G(?=[^@\n]*$)).(?=.*[^@\n]\\.)","*")
$9 ==> "j******e@e********n.com"
```

Answer (score 0):

Is a regex a requirement?  [¯(°_o)/¯](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/)

You could also do it that way:

```
int atIndex = email.indexOf("@");
int lastDotIndex = email.lastIndexOf(".");

String maskedEmail = IntStream.range(0, email.length())
        .boxed()
        .map(i -> i==0 || (i>=atIndex-1 && i<=atIndex+1) || i>=lastDotIndex ? 
                   email.charAt(i) : '*')
        .map(String::valueOf)
        .collect(Collectors.joining());
```